# C# WPF - Conflicto metodo mover ventana y MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf

estoy haciendo programa que tiene un método que me permite arrastrar la ventana haciendo click en cualquier lugar de esta.

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        this.DragMove();
    }
```

Y este otro que sirve para modificar el Path de un archivo de texto, en el que salta un MessageBox con Si, No (y posteriormente un FolderBrowserDialog)

```
private void LbFolderSettings_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to modify the Historial.txt path?", "Confirm path change", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

        if (messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            metodesPath.EscriurePathHistorialAConfig();
        }
    }
```

El problema viene cuando hago click en las respuestas si o no del messagebox. O bien selecciono la carpeta del FolderBrowser.
Se produce un conflicto que devuelve este error en el primer metodo (en la linea - **this.Dragmove();**):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sólo se puede llamar a DragMove cuando el botón principal del mouse está presionado.'

El error solo se produce cuando uso los botones Si o No del Messagebox o le doy a Aceptar o Cancelar en el FolderBrowserDialog. Estos 2 los puedo arrastrar y dar click encima sin problema.

Parece que cuando das click en los bonotes y vuelve a la ventana principal detecta que estas intentando arrastrar la ventana.

Como podría solucionar el problema?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Fijate que tu problema no es el messagebox, es de antes.. porque el evento que levanta el messagebox se pisa con el otro.. uno usa mousedown, y el otro OnMouseLeftButtonDown. Uno es para todos los botones, el otro solo para el principal...

Comment: Gracias por la informacion! Mirare bien toda la documentación de la que me hablas!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de enrutamiento de eventos, puedes leer más información al respecto en [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview).

Tu problema es fácil de solucionar, rompe con el enrutamiento del evento cambiando el estado del mismo y dándolo por terminado mediante la propiedad "Handled" del parámetro "EventArgs".

En tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
private void LbFolderSettings_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult messageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to modify the Historial.txt path?", "Confirm path change", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);

    if (messageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        metodesPath.EscriurePathHistorialAConfig();
    }

    // Aquí se indica que ha sido manejado y por tanto deja de propagarse por el resto de controles
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Como dices, ahora funciona perfectamente.

De todas formas encontré una solución alternativa poniendo el codigo que me permite mover la ventana dentro de un try catch con el catch vacio:
`protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {           
            try
            {
                base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
                this.DragMove();
            }
            catch { }
        }`

Supongo que esto es una mala práctica pero también funciona. Debería cambiarlo y usar el e.handeled=true?

Comment: Gerard tal y como dices dejar el try-cach sería una mala práctica, debes conocer bien el entorno en el que trabajas, por tanto en este caso entiende bien el concepto del enrutamiento de eventos y te servirá más adelante para otras cosas. Me alegro haber podido ayudarte.